# Why do I receive these values of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in VS Code js file and running it through windows command prompt :

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

How come its giving me as an output :

```
1
2
undefined
3
4
undefined
5
6
undefined
```

Where does the undefined come from ? This doesnt happen when running it say on the FreeCodeCamp IDE
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: what is the range of `j` values? Which array are you testing for length in the `for(var j...)` loop?

Comment: `arr.length === 3; arr[i].length === 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not considering length on inner arrays.

In the second for loop, you should be considering the length of each array item. In your existing example, 3 x 3 iterations are taking place hence you are seeing 9 values in the log.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the error lies within your second loop condition :`j < arr.length` should be `j < arr[i].length`